# How to set permissions on directory, that will bequeath its permissions to all subdirectories?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, file-permissions, setuid

Is there a way to set permissions on a *nix directory, so that when a subdirectory is created, the subdirectory will be created with all the permissions as the parent directory?

---

There's the [following,](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) but it does not seem to do all that I ask for:

> On most systems, if a directory’s set-group-ID bit is set, newly
>   created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly
>   created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent
>   directory. On a few systems, a directory’s set-user-ID bit has a
>   similar effect on the ownership of new subfiles and the set-user-ID
>   bits of new subdirectories. These mechanisms let users share files
>   more easily, by lessening the need to use chmod or chown to share new
>   files.

Answer (score 3):

When a sub-folder is created, the permission of the new sub-folder is defined by:

1. The properties of the user created the directory:

   a. user-id

   b. group id's
2. The defined `umask`
3. The parents folder `default ACL` (if exists)

**Note: More info can be found in [acl man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)**

> OBJECT CREATION AND DEFAULT ACLs
>
> The access ACL of a file object is initialized when the object is
>   created with any of the creat(), mkdir(), mknod(), mkfifo(), or open()
>   functions. If a default ACL is associated with a directory, the mode
>   parameter to the functions creating file objects and the default ACL
>   of the directory are used to determine the ACL of the new object:
>
> **1. The new object inherits the default ACL of the containing directory as its access ACL.**
>
> **2. The access ACL entries corresponding to the file permission bits are modified so that they contain no permissions that are not
>   contained in the permissions specified by the mode parameter.**
>
> **If no default ACL is associated with a directory, the mode parameter to the functions creating file objects and the file creation mask (see
>   umask(2)) are used to determine the ACL of the new object:**
>
> 1. The new object is assigned an access ACL containing entries of tag types ACL_USER_OBJ, ACL_GROUP_OBJ, and ACL_OTHER. The permissions of
>      these entries are set to the permissions specified by the file
>      creation mask.
> 2. The access ACL entries corresponding to the file permission bits are modified so that they contain no permissions that are not
>      contained in the permissions specified by the mode parameter.

**Instructions how to set a default ACL [were copied from this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)**

> ```
> chmod g+s <directory>  //set gid 
> setfacl -d -m g::rwx /<directory>  //set group to rwx default 
> setfacl -d -m o::rx /<directory>   //set other
> ```
>
> Next we can verify:
>
> ```
> getfacl /<directory>
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> # file: ../<directory>/
> # owner: <user>
> # group: media
> # flags: -s-
> user::rwx
> group::rwx
> other::r-x
> default:user::rwx
> default:group::rwx
> default:other::r-x
> ```

**More info about `umask` can be found in [umask man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)**

> ```
>    umask() sets the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to
>    mask & 0777 (i.e., only the file permission bits of mask are used),
>    and returns the previous value of the mask.
>
>    The umask is used by open(2), mkdir(2), and other system calls that
>    create files to modify the permissions placed on newly created files
>    or directories.  Specifically, permissions in the umask are turned
>    off from the mode argument to open(2) and mkdir(2).
>
>    Alternatively, if the parent directory has a default ACL (see
>    acl(5)), the umask is ignored, the default ACL is inherited, the
>    permission bits are set based on the inherited ACL, and permission
>    bits absent in the mode argument are turned off.  For example, the
>    following default ACL is equivalent to a umask of 022:
>
>        u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x
>
>    Combining the effect of this default ACL with a mode argument of 0666
>    (rw-rw-rw-), the resulting file permissions would be 0644 (rw-
>    r--r--).
>
>    The constants that should be used to specify mask are described under
> ```

Comment: @boardrider - if I've answered your question please accept/up-vote it